# Unable to find a version of Silverlight Developer runtime installed. Please install the silverlight developer runtime

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am using visual studio 2012 professional version. I am trying to use Light Switch.  I am getting the error : "Unable to find a version of Silverlight Developer runtime installed. Please install the silverlight developer run time."

I am trying to open the project

File -> New Project -> Templates -> Light Switch -> Light Switch Application(visual c#)

Then I am flashing with this error.

I downloaded silver light from the link http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/
How to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this issue before as well and I got around the problem by performing Windows Updates as soon as I installed VS 2012 Pro, its missing a Service Pack I'm assuming like mine was and after the update I was able to install and run Light Switch with no problem. I hope this helps you my friend. Good luck